# PrimeNG: Editable dataTable column

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a data table and i am trying to make the column careOfferingSpaceAvailableId  editable then once user edits i want to update that row column also in the database.

1.) However for some reason the UI does not render this column as editable

2.) I have a "next" button and once clicked  i do not know how to grab the values that user enters into the spaces available editable column. I need to grab each spaceAvailable input along with its careOfferingSpaceAvailableId to update to the database

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="this.careOfferingSpaceList" [editable]="true" selectionMode="single" rows="25" [responsive]="true"
      [loading]="false">
      <p-column field="id" [editable]="true" hidden="true"></p-column>
      <p-column field="weekNo" [editable]="true" header="Offerings">
        <ng-template let-careOfferingSpace="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <span> Week {{careOfferingSpace.weekNo}} </span>
        </ng-template>
      </p-column>
      <p-column field="startDate" [editable]="true" header="Date">
        <ng-template let-careOfferingSpace="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <span> {{careOfferingSpace.startDate}} - {{careOfferingSpace.endDate}} </span>
        </ng-template>
      </p-column>
      <p-column field="careOfferingSpaceAvailableId" hidden="true" header="Space Available Id" [editable]="true">
      </p-column>
      <p-column field="spaceAvailable" header="Spaces Available" [editable]="true">
      </p-column>

    </p-dataTable>
```

You can see even if i click space available column i cant type data

[image: You can see]

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can't edit your cells because you added `selectionMode` property to the table so if you click on a cell, it will select it and won't select the cell.

Also, just for your information, `this` is useless in your HTML so you can replace

```
[value]="this.careOfferingSpaceList"
```

with

```
[value]="careOfferingSpaceList"
```

---

2.) When you click on Next button, you just have to browse `careOfferingSpaceList` object to grab what you need :

```
nextAction() {
     this.careOfferingSpaceList.forEach(function(careOfferingSpace) {
       console.log('careOfferingSpaceAvailableId-spaceAvailable : ' + careOfferingSpace.careOfferingSpaceAvailableId + '-' + careOfferingSpace.spaceAvailable);
     })
}
```

---

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZPx7s3Nc3z1SGiMan9O?p=preview)